# Integrating several shell scripts into one script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I would like to integrate a few short scripts into one script where I can update an argument for the input file from the command line. I am going through 22 files and counting lines where `$5!="1"`. 
Here is a sample head of the input file:
Currently, I have the following 3 short scripts:

```
CHROM POS   N_ALLELES N_CHR {FREQ}
2   45895   2   162 0.993827    0.00617284
2   45953   2   162 0.993827    0.00617284
2   264985  2   162 1   0
2   272051  2   162 0.944444    0.0555556
```

1) count lines (saved as wcYRI.sh): `$5!="1"{sum++}END{print sum}`

2) apply linecount (saved as check-annos.sh): `awk -f wcYRI.sh ~/folder$1/file$1`

3) apply linecount for 22 files, sum the output:

```
    for i in {1..22}; 
    do sh check-annos.sh $i; done 
    | awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

Its relatively simple, but sometimes script 1 gets a little longer for data files that look like this:

```
Chr Start   End Ref Alt Func.refGene    Gene.refGene    ExonicFunc.refGene  AAChange.refGene    LJB2_SIFT   LJB2_PolyPhen2_HDIV LJB2_PP2_HDIV_Pred  LJB2_PolyPhen2_HVAR LJB2_PolyPhen2_HVAR_Pred    LJB2_LRT    LJB2_LRT_Pred   LJB2_MutationTaster LJB2_MutationTaster_Pred    LJB_MutationAssessor    LJB_MutationAssessor_Pred   LJB2_FATHMM LJB2_GERP++ LJB2_PhyloP LJB2_SiPhy
16  101593  101593  C   T   exonic  POLR3K  nonsynonymous SNV   POLR3K:NM_016310:exon2:c.G164A:p.G55E   0.000000    0.997   D   0.913   D   0.000000    D   0.999989    D   2.205   medium  0.99    5.3 2.477000    17.524
```

...and I am using an awk file like this (performing an array match) as input -f to script 2 above:

```
NR==FNR{
    arr[$1$2];next
}   
    $1$2 in arr && $0~/exonic/&&/nonsynonymous SNV/{nonsyn++};
    $1$2 in arr && $0~/exonic/&&/synonymous SNV/ && $0!~/nonsynonymous/{syn++}
END{
    print nonsyn,"nonsyn YRI","\t",syn,"YRI syn"
}
```

My goal is to integrate this process a bit more so I don't need to go into script 2 and change the `~/folder$1/file$1` each time-- I'd like to be able to use `~/folder$1/file$1` as an input at the command line. However when I try to use something like this in a for-loop at the command line, it doesn't accept `$1` the way it does when `$1` is built into a separate script being called by the for-do-done loop (as in script 3 --i.e. script 3 will take script 2, but I can't just enter the contents of script 2 explicitly into the for-loop as an argument(s)).

I am actually not so concerned about having a separate AWK file to handle the line parsing, the main thing annoying me is that I am modifying script 2 for each folder/file set, and I would like to be able to do this from the command line so that the script knows when I tell it `~/folder$1/file$1`, to cycle through numbers 1-22 and I so can save one universal script for this process, since I have many folder/file combinations to look at.

Any advice is appreciated for shortening the pipeline in general, but specifically the command line argument problem is bugging me a lot!

Comment: What do you mean by `I am using an awk file like this as input -f to script 2 above` ?

Comment: Sometimes my pipeline uses the array matching script that I gave above, rather than the shorter $5!="1" for script 1, depending on the files I am processing. But I don't care that much about the awk script, its mostly that I would like to build a script where I can use `~/folder$1/file$1` as the input

Comment: I think this is an interesting question, but I have to sign off for 6 hours now.. I'll have a look at it later though. See you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. In the meantime I think I might try to post a simpler version of the problem and see if anyone bites ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, I see two ways to handle it. If the path format is consistent (i.e. the number always occurs twice, in the same positions), you could make the script accept the parts of the path as two different parameters. The script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
folderPrefix="$1"
filePrefix="$2"

for num in {1..22}; do
    awk -f wcYRI.sh "$folderPrefix$num/$filePrefix$num"
done | 
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

... and then you'd run it with `./scriptname ~/folder file`. Alternately, if you need to be able to define the folder/file path format more flexibly, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for num in {1..22}; do
    eval "awk -f wcYRI.sh $1"
done | 
    awk '{sum+=$1}END{print sum}'
```

... and then run it with `./scriptname '~/folder$num/file$num'`. Note that the single-quotes are needed here so that the `$var` references don't get expanded until `eval` forces them to be.

BTW, the file wcYRI.sh is an awk script, not a shell script, so I'd recommend changing its file extension to prevent confusion. Actually, the preferred way to do this (for both shell and awk scripts) is to add a shebang line as the first line in the script (see my examples above; for an awk script it would be `#!/usr/bin/awk -f`), then make the script executable, and then run it with just `./scriptname` and let the shebang take care of specifying the interpreter (sh, bash, awk -f, whatever).

Comment: Could you tell me what you mean by the $var references?

Comment: One problem I am having is that my filenames look like this: `~/annovar/genome_files/chr$num_SNPs/yri_nonsyn_chr$num_derived.freq` and when I try to evaluate it seems to miss the `$num` section...

Comment: I'm using `$var` to refer to any variable expansion (`$1`, `$num`, etc). On your second comment, you're probably running into trouble with it thinking you're referring to variables named `num_SNPs` and `num_derived` -- to avoid this problem, put `{}` around the variable names: `~/annovar/genome_files/chr${num}_SNPs/yri_nonsyn_chr${num}_derived.freq`

Comment: Thanks, that worked and solved several of my problems in one go!